# Compile Readline for x86 system (static mode)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile, readline

I am writing a program in QT Creator, for the x86 architecture, using Debian 9 x86. The program will use GNU Readline library [8.0]. Also, my program must be statically built (QT is already statically built). For this I downloaded Readline from [here.](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/)
Then performed the configuration for the static assembly:

```
./configure —prefix=/home/out/readlinelibs/ —enable-static —with-curses
```

then i performed the construction:

```
make
```

and installing libraries

```
make install
```

In QT's pro file I added the path to the libraries:

```
LIBS += -L/home/out/readlinelibs/lib -static -lreadline -ltinfo
```

When compiling the program I get the following error in QT:

```
error: cannot find -ltinfo
```

How to build readline in static mode? Thanks.

P.S.: in Debian x64 I also built readline and everything works well.

Comment: tinfo must be available as a static library as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the lack of a tinfo library, as **mbieren** advised. I performed the installation on a 64-bit system as follows:

1. Added ability to install 32-bit packages:

   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
2. I scanned the package and found that i need. You can do the scan so:

   sudo apt-cache search tinfo
3. Finally i installed that i need:

   sudo apt-get install lib32tinfo5 lib32tinfo-dev

Now the compilation of my program for 32-bit architecture is completed successfully!